# how to add a sub folder inside the root folder of the app through android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android app in which I have three layouts:
First:- "list view" in which list of items are shown.
Second:- "layout with a button "click pictures"
Third:- "Camera"

I want that when a user click on a item on the list view layout of android app, a sub folder should be created inside the app folder, named same as that of the item in the list view layout.And then the photos clicked afterwards should get stored in that created sub-folder inside the folder of the app.

I hope that my explanation is pretty clear. Please guide me how to achieve this.
Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your difficulty? creating a directry is a matter of calling 1 method, I doubt this is what is blocking you

Answer (score 0):

You can add folder or directory like this.

```
String value = input.getText();
   // Do something with value!

   //This is where you would put your make directory code
   File photos = new File(getFilesDir(),value);
   photos.mkdir();
```

Put this code where ever you want like under in `Button`'s click or in method.

Hope this help you.